# Failure to create hibernation partition on GPT SSD boot drive

Tags: partitioning, hibernate, gpt

I've searched a number of forums and am surprised no one seems to have had the same problem as me. I have only one SSD (Samsung EVO) which is also my boot drive (UEFI, z97 board) for my desktop machine. My other drives are all RAID arrays. I'm trying to enable Intel Rapid Start Tech (IRST) after finding I couldn't install the software and in the BIOS it was showing no suitable partition.

When using `diskpart.exe`, following the user guide, it all goes ok until I select the volume and try to set the id at `D3BFE2DE-3DAF-11DF-BA40-E3A556D89593`.

Upon doing this, Windows Disk Management shows the partition going from *Raw* to *Healthy (Primary)*, instead of *Hibernation partition*, as I've seen on other people's screenshots. I've tried many things over and over again for hours to no avail. The BIOS still shows no suitable partition and I can't install the IRST software.

The only things I can think that it could be are either that I installed the OS before I set the BIOS to 'Enable IRST' (SSD was pre-formatted from Samsung?) or when I first tried I set the ID to 84 on my first attempt before I read on another forum that was for MBR only.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Sorry Luke, I gave up in the end after much trying. Just can't figure out why it doesn't recognise the sector as I need it to. If I try a new build from scratch (windows 10?) I will give it another go but for now just enter my pc into sleep mode instead as this is low power although not as good as IRST.